# foreach thing `cat file.txt` loop - how to remove newline character from next line? and append to current? - prevent word splitting in tcsh

Tags: awk, newline, cat, tcsh

I have a text file that I am reading line by line using foreach `cat file.txt` in tcsh. The last field sometimes has a comment. For some reason when I am reading each line in the file, cat (correctly) does not break up my comment into words (this is correct) during the initial `cat file.txt`(on the command line). But it does break up the comment field when I do foreach thing (`cat file.txt`) and echo.

When I start processing the file with awk (assigning fields to variables and soforth) the comment in the last field starts breaking up into a new line. This is what it is being processed like:

```
 SAMEWORD,1111,2622,33,.00000,.000000,1,0,9,0,9,0,
 SAMEWORD,1231,2222,33,.00000,.000000,1,0,9,0,9,0,
 SAMEWORD,1411,2422,34,.00000,.000000,1,0,9,0,9,0,COMMENT
 STARTS
 HERE
 BUT
 IS 
 BEING
 BROKEN 
 INTO
 NEW
 LINES
 SAMEWORD,1441,2672,53,.00000,.000000,1,0,9,0,2,0,
 SAMEWORD,1351,2372,63,.00000,.000000,1,0,1,0,9,0,
 SAMEWORD,1351,2372,63,.00000,.000000,1,0,6,0,9,0,
 SAMEWORD,1351,2372,63,.00000,.000000,1,0,6,0,9,0,HERE
 IS
 ANOTHER
 EXAMPLE
 SAMEWORD,1441,2672,53,.00000,.000000,1,0,9,0,2,0,
 SAMEWORD,1441,2672,53,.00000,.000000,1,0,9,0,2,0,
```

I tried using printf instead of print in my awk command but that hasn't helped the problem. If I am reading a current line the last field isn't "" then how do I append the next line to the current last field without having to lose my place in the main for loop?

[I should add that I need to process with awk because in my script I'm checking the first field for a condition (for example, if ($firstfield == "SAMEWORD") then...) and this is where the last field is, for some reason, being broken into new lines/records.]

I've tried so many variations of sed, awk, tr, cat, and I can't seem to come up with anything that works.

Also acceptable would be a way to (while on the current line) check what the first field is in the next line and if it's not SAMEWORD then append to last field of current line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the problem might be solved by preventing the `tcsh` `foreach` loop from splitting  lines into words, so that the input lines are passed through intact.

Try double-quoting the command substitution:

```
foreach line ("`cat file.txt`")
    # process line with awk
end
```

On a side note: can't you just let `awk` process the input file directly?

Comment: FML. I am too embarrassed to admit how much time I spent trying things when it was quotes this entire time. THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I think your simple suggestion is going to work!! Amazing. Regarding your question, I am not sure what you mean about how I could let awk process the file directly. Theoretically I could maybe try an awk script though I haven't written one before. I change a lot of the fields in each record and a combination of forloop and awk generally works out ok. If you are bored and would enjoy clarifying with an example, feel free.

Comment: @user3312062: :) That's what StackOverflow is for. If my answer solved your problem, please click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted. This helps others find useful information and - full disclosure - also increases my reputation.

Comment: @user3312062 don't be embarrassed, this is an example of why you should not use csh for scripting. Google "csh why not".